# Would using vinyl wall base be a good solution to cover a gap between doorframe and flooring?

Tags: flooring, baseboard, gap

[image]

There's a small gap between the flooring and the bottom of the door frame to my garage. Would using black vinyl floor base cut to height to cover the gap look odd?

Comment: Only you can decide if it will look odd. Voting to close - decorating advice.

Comment: Cut down a piece of whatever it is you're using as your baseboard trim in the room so that it fits under the door sill. Covers the gap. Provides continuity.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in your garage, you could probably use whatever is handy.  Just make sure to put something solid behind it so the floor base has something good and solid to attach to without gaps behind it.

But with that much height difference, I might suggest putting some sort of short ramp rather than a solid 2" height bump, as I'm sure you'll want to roll things in and out on occasion, and having a short ramp (even 6" run or so for the 2" rise) would help anything with wheels roll successfully over that much easier than trying to lift it by hand.  Also, the 2" might be considered a tripping hazard, so putting a ramp there would help reduce the tripping possibilities at that spot.

Comment: The picture is actually from inside the house looking at the garage door, so a ramp isn't really an option there. Though it still is kind of a tripping hazard...